# jquery autocomplete pass combobox as parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-autocomplete

I want to pass combobox as parameter but the autocomplete take only the first option value from combobox this my code
  Jquery:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var op="";
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#drp").change(function(){
                op=$("#drp").val();
            });
            $("#tag").keypress(function(){
                op=$("#drp").val();
            });
            $("#tag").autocomplete("search_all_check.php", {
                selectFirst: true,
                extraParams: { param: op }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

and html:

```
 <select  name="users" id="drp"  class="search_department" >
                   <option name="graid" id="grade_id" value="grade">Graid</option>
                    <option name="div" id="div_id"  value="division">Division</option>
                    <option name="department" id="dep_id"  value="department">Department</option>
                    <option name="card" id="card_id"  value="id_card">Id Card</option>
                    <option name="education" id="education_id"  value="education">Education</option>
                    <option name="age" id="age_id"  value="age">Age</option>
                 </select>
            <input type="text" name="text" id="tag" value="" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `multiple` attribute to your `<select>` element:

```
<select  name="users" id="drp"  class="search_department" multiple >
```

Comment: `$('select').val()`  will return array if select is `multiple`

Comment: thank you but multiple did not solve my problem and any time autocomplete fire it get first value of dropdownbox